# Initial values, initialized using JS, not changing while updating data in Django Model Form

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

**models.py**

```
class Package(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    diagnosis=models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=CASCADE)
    treatment=models.ForeignKey(Treatment, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=models.ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    date_of_admission=models.DateField(default=None)
    max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    total_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Based on the `treatment` and `patient_type`, I want `max_fractions` and `total_package` to be given initial values. For that I wrote a JS function:

```
function mf(){
    tt_select = document.getElementById("id_package_form-treatment");
    tt = tt_select.options[tt_select.selectedIndex].text;
    ptt_select = document.getElementById("id_package_form-patient_type");
    ptt = ptt_select.options[ptt_select.selectedIndex].text;
    max = document.getElementById("id_package_form-max_fractions");

    if (tt=="MVTR" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    max.value=40;
    else if (tt=="MVTR" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    max.value=40;
    else if (tt=="MVTR" && ptt=="CASH")
    max.value=40;

    else if (tt=="CRFP" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    max.value=40;
    else if (tt=="CRFP" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    max.value=40;
    else if (tt=="CRFP" && ptt=="CASH")
    max.value=40;

    else if (tt=="5DTYU" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    max.value=30;
    else if (tt=="5DTYU" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    max.value=30;
    else if (tt=="5DTYU" && ptt=="PMJAY")
    max.value=30;
    else if (tt=="5DTYU" && ptt=="CASH")
    max.value=30;

    else if (tt=="FRTC" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    max.value=40;
    else if (tt=="FRTC" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    max.value=40;
    else if (tt=="FRTC" && ptt=="PMJAY")
    max.value=30;
    else if (tt=="FRTC" && ptt=="CASH")
    max.value=35;

    else if (tt=="PALLATIVE" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    max.value=10;
    else if (tt=="PALLATIVE" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    max.value=10;
    else if (tt=="PALLATIVE" && ptt=="CASH")
    max.value=5;

    else if (tt=="RADICAL" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    max.value=0;
    else if (tt=="RADICAL" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    max.value=0;
    else if (tt=="RADICAL" && ptt=="CASH")
    max.value=0;

    else if (tt=="ADJUVANT" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    max.value=0;
    else if (tt=="ADJUVANT" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    max.value=0;
    else if (tt=="ADJUVANT" && ptt=="CASH")
    max.value=0;

    else
    max.value=0
}


function tp(){
    tt_select = document.getElementById("id_package_form-treatment");
    tt = tt_select.options[tt_select.selectedIndex].text;
    ptt_select = document.getElementById("id_package_form-patient_type");
    ptt = ptt_select.options[ptt_select.selectedIndex].text;
    total = document.getElementById("id_package_form-total_package");

    if (tt=="MVTR" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    total.value=150000;
    else if (tt=="MVTR" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    total.value=150000;
    else if (tt=="MVTR" && ptt=="CASH")
    total.value=235000;

    else if (tt=="CRFP" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    total.value=100000;
    else if (tt=="CRFP" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    total.value=100000;
    else if (tt=="CRFP" && ptt=="CASH")
    total.value=170000;

    else if (tt=="5DTYU" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    total.value=75000;
    else if (tt=="5DTYU" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    total.value=75000;
    else if (tt=="5DTYU" && ptt=="PMJAY")
    total.value=70000;
    else if (tt=="5DTYU" && ptt=="CASH")
    total.value=110000;

    else if (tt=="FRTC" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    total.value=150000;
    else if (tt=="FRTC" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    total.value=150000;
    else if (tt=="FRTC" && ptt=="PMJAY")
    total.value=120000;
    else if (tt=="FRTC" && ptt=="CASH")
    total.value=195000;

    else if (tt=="PALLATIVE" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    total.value=20000;
    else if (tt=="PALLATIVE" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    total.value=20000;
    else if (tt=="PALLATIVE" && ptt=="CASH")
    total.value=25000;

    else if (tt=="RADICAL" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    total.value=50000;
    else if (tt=="RADICAL" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    total.value=50000;
    else if (tt=="RADICAL" && ptt=="CASH")
    total.value=80000;

    else if (tt=="ADJUVANT" && ptt=="JTCPR")
    total.value=35000;
    else if (tt=="ADJUVANT" && ptt=="JTCPR/PC")
    total.value=35000;
    else if (tt=="ADJUVANT" && ptt=="CASH")
    total.value=70000;

    else
    total.value=0
}
```

**forms.py**

```
class PackageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Package
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
           "patient_type" : forms.Select(attrs={"onblur":"mf();"}),
           "max_fractions" : forms.NumberInput(attrs={"onfocus":"mf();", "onblur":"tp();"}),
           "total_package" : forms.NumberInput(attrs={"onfocus":"tp();", "onblur":"onLoad();"}),
           'date_of_admission': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

It all works fine while creating an instance. The form fills in both the fields as per the commands. But when I go to update the data in the model via:

```
def update_package_view(request, id):
    if request.method=='POST':
        print(request.POST)
        pkg=Package.objects.get(pk=id)
        print(pkg)
        form=PackageForm(request.POST, instance=pkg)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        pkg=Package.objects.get(pk=id)
        form=PackageForm(instance=pkg)
    return render(request, 'account/update_package.html', {'form':form})
```

And I change the `patient_type` or `treatment` or both, `max_fractions` and `total_package` remain unchanged. What's wrong?

Comment: The `value` property of html input elements are strings, so you could try wrapping the numbers in "".

Comment: @TaipanRex But it works just fine when I create a new instance. Why would it behave differently while edition the data?

Comment: @TaipanRex Still I changed it to strings, yet no outcome!